# boost crc optimized fails on arm

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, arm

I have a program that I compile both for x86 and arm (rpi2). I'm using boost for crc implementation and have a problem with it failing on arm platform.

After debugging I found that the crc calculations where off on arm. I wrote these small test cases to pinpoint the problem:

```
namespace
{
    unsigned char const  data[] = { 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39 };
    std::size_t const    data_len = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
    uint16_t const expected = 0x29B1;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_non_optimized){
    boost::crc_basic<16>  crc_basic(0x1021, 0xFFFF, 0, false, false);
    crc_basic.process_bytes(data, data_len);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(crc_basic.checksum(), expected);
}


BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_optimized) {
    boost::crc_optimal<16, 0x1021, 0xFFFF, 0, false, false> crc_optimal;
    crc_optimal.process_bytes(data, data_len);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(crc_optimal.checksum(), expected);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_function) {
    uint16_t checksum = boost::crc<16, 0x1021, 0xFFFF, 0, false, false>(data, data_len);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(checksum, expected);
}
```

All three test cases pass on x86. But on arm only the crc_basic test pass. The other two fails:

```
test/boost_crc_test.cpp(41): check crc_optimal.checksum() == expected has failed [29299 != 10673]
test/boost_crc_test.cpp(46): check checksum == expected has failed [29299 != 10673]
```

Boost version 1.63.0

Compiler: gcc (GCC) 6.3.1 20170109

I'm rather surprised to come across something like this with boost. Any ideas on what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it turned out the problem was only present with -O3. Not with -O2 or lower.

Further, upgrading gcc to 7.1.1 20170516 also solved the problem. Even with -O3

Comment: "Solved the problem" or "removed the symptom"? It could still be undefined behaviour.

Comment: In case anyone wants to easily run this with sanitizers enabled: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d13bb5ff9fb1f7ad

Comment: ok, good input. All I know is that now the program seems to work and the ~40 test cases that failed before in various places now all pass. That said. I don't really know how to interpret the output from the sanitize flag. Are you telling me it is unsafe to keep using O3 and the boost crc function?

Comment: I don't expect UB there. But there is a small chance the code is actually doing something unsavory. I'll try to check (Any tips on getting the ARM toolchain on Linux or Windows?)

Comment: ok, thanks! I'm using arch linux but I havn't set up a complete cross compiler. What we do is to have the build server run an agent on a real rpi2 and then we run several distcc slaves on virtual x86 machines cross compiling for arm according to https://archlinuxarm.org/wiki/Distcc_Cross-Compiling this works well. Some files fail to build on the slaves and are then recompiled on the native architecture. In any case. The ng-toolchain for armv7h on the linked page is what we use.